# How can I integrate result of API into container CSS?

Tags: html, css

CSS is a container, and I expect to integrate API field value result into container. Could you please indicate how to proceed please?

Have a good day.

head

```
<style>

.container {
background-color:#fff;
border-radius:20px;
padding:100px 60px;
width:200px;
box-shadow: rgba(50,50, 93, 0.25) 0px 6px 12px -2px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3) 0px 3px 7px -3px;
}   

</style>
```

body

```
<div class="container">METEO CHAVENAY</div>
<div id='temperature'>"temperature"</div> c° (temperature)
<span id='pressure'>"pressure"</span> hpa (pression par rapport au niveau de la mer)
<span id='visibility'>"visibility"</span> km (visibilité horizontale)
<span id='windspeed'>"windspeed"</span> km/h (vitesse du vent)
<span id='winddire'>"winddire"</span> ° (direction du vent)
<span id='clouds'>"clouds"</span> % (couverture nuageuse)
<span id='sunrise'>"sunrise"</span> (Heure du lever du soleil)
<span id='sunset'>"sunset"</span> (Heure du coucher du soleil)
<span id='timezone'>"timezone"</span> H GMT Time zone
</div>
```

Comment: "CSS is a container" isn't a statement that makes sense to me. Could you clarify? I don't understand the question.

Answer (score 0):

try to put the fields INSIDE the div block with that css class:

```
<div class="container">
    METEO CHAVENAY
    <div id='temperature'>"temperature"</div> c° (temperature)
    <span id='pressure'>"pressure"</span> hpa (pression par rapport au niveau de la mer)
    <span id='visibility'>"visibility"</span> km (visibilité horizontale)
    <span id='windspeed'>"windspeed"</span> km/h (vitesse du vent)
    <span id='winddire'>"winddire"</span> ° (direction du vent)
    <span id='clouds'>"clouds"</span> % (couverture nuageuse)
    <span id='sunrise'>"sunrise"</span> (Heure du lever du soleil)
    <span id='sunset'>"sunset"</span> (Heure du coucher du soleil)
    <span id='timezone'>"timezone"</span> H GMT Time zone
    </div>
</div>
```

Then, why all those double quotes?

And, why not put everything BETWEEN the div or span blocks? Normally there is no need to put text outside those blocks. But that is not the CSS problem.

To get `width` working on the div, you might want to add in the css:

```
display: inline-block;
```

It looks like you need more experience. I would focus on the basics first, before using complicated CSS like box-shadow.